# Output a String to console with a specific color

Tags: string, kotlin, colors

Look at this simple piece of code:

```
var name = "Alex"
println(name)
```

Is there a way to assign a color to the string without making changes in *println* command?
In other words, only the *name* variable could be shown in (say) green color instead of default white color.

Comment: Can you elaborate and what is the use case for this? Maybe we can suggest a better way to achieve what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ANSI escape code to add a color to strings. To print a green string, use `"\u001b[32m"`.

```
fun main() {
    val greenColor = "\u001b[32m"
    val reset = "\u001b[0m" // to reset color to the default
    val name = greenColor + "Alex" + reset // Add green only to Alex
    println(name)
}
```

For more information, read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors

Comment: Thanks, just one more question. Is there a way to add color to this _val name: String_ ? I mean without defining it or giving it a value.

Comment: @Alex_89 Unless you use a library like JANSI, I think there is no way.

Comment: This code example will continue to print in green color until you set it back to default.
You can do so by appending "\u001B[0m" to the name variable.

Comment: @NirYudo yeah, I updated the answer to only add green to Alex. It's my bad.

Answer (score 3):

In a typical console environment, the color of the output text is controlled by the console itself and cannot be directly manipulated by the code. However, you can achieve colored output by utilizing special formatting escape sequences that are recognized by some consoles.

Here's an example of how you can use ANSI escape sequences to print the name variable in green color:

```
val name = "\u001B[32mAlex\u001B[0m"
println(name)
```

In the above code, \u001B[32m is the escape sequence for setting the color to green, and \u001B[0m is the escape sequence for resetting the color to the default. By surrounding the name variable with these escape sequences, the console should interpret it and display the text in green color.

Please note that the effectiveness of ANSI escape sequences may vary depending on the console or terminal emulator being used. It's recommended to test the code in the target environment to ensure compatibility and desired output.

Comment: Worth noting that if you redirect your output you will end up with garbage.